# duplicate block in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops

I am a newbe in HTML. I have a few items that I want to duplicate. Idealy I would want to have a for loop on this entire block. I saw that it is possible in php, but I don't want to install it.. is there a way to do it with HTML or JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- duplicate from here -->
<h4>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h4>
<ul>
  <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY.</li>
  <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY</li>
  <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY</li>
</ul>


<audio controls>
  <source src="zzz.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<div class="form-group"><label for="WWWWW">VVVVVV:</label>

<div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" cols="250" id="abab" name="abab" required="" rows="15">
</textarea></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- duplicate to here-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Install what? Php? You don't need to install it, most webhosts have php support and all you need to do is change the file name to .php

Comment: If he want's to test his website on his own localhost he will need to install it though

Comment: @Eric There is really no need to test such basic code. If it works, good. If not just change the code til it works.

Comment: But how will you know if it works before testing it first :), and I personally like testing it on my computer and not on my main website, so that if it wouldn't work your main website would still be functional

Comment: @Eric you use GET for example to create a debug mode on your page. I have that. If I write ...?debug=true on my page it goes in to debug mode and dumps out variables and stuff I need to debug the page.

Comment: Either way. The page seems to be at square 1. And this code that may or may not work is still such small part that it's possible to debug on a live page

Comment: Ow I didn't know that, but anyway this is not really important for this question. He probably has his reasons for not using PHP.

Comment: @Eric well it's not a standard feature of php it's something I have added so that I can develope on my live page while users won't notice anything. When I developed a feature that needs to go "live" I simply remove the if() that looks for debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop using `javascript`, below code will duplicate the block 5 times

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + `
      <h4>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY.</li>
        <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY</li>
        <li>YYYYYYYYYYYYY</li>
      </ul>


      <audio controls>
        <source src="zzz.wav" type="audio/wav">
      </audio>

      <div class="form-group"><label for="WWWWW">VVVVVV:</label>

      <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" cols="250" id="abab" name="abab" required="" rows="15">
      </textarea></div>
      </div>
      </div>
  `;
}
```

Also learn about [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to know `back-tick` and `expression` which might come handy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using jquery or javascript

Attach jquery library after `</html>` and add following line of code at the very bottom

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').append($('body').html());
 });
</script>
```